# How can I align a struct to a specified byte boundary?

Tags: rust, memory-alignment

I need to align a struct to a 16 byte boundary in Rust. It seems possible to give hints about alignment through the [`repr` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#representations), but it doesn't support this exact use case.

A functional test of what I'm trying to achieve is a type `Foo` such that

```
assert_eq!(mem::align_of::<Foo>(), 16);
```

or alternatively, a struct `Bar` with a field `baz` such that

```
println!("{:p}", Bar::new().baz);
```

always prints a number divisible by 16.

Is this currently possible in Rust? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a struct in the heap with a specific alignment? I'm not aware of alignment for stack-allocated types, but the unstable [`allocate`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rt/heap/fn.allocate.html) does have an alignment argument.

Comment: Also, you mention packing as decreasing alignment; do you mean to say that you need to have a *member* of a struct always at a specific alignment? You may want to bolster your question with some example code, ASCII-art memory diagrams, or more prose describing why you need to do this so that all the people smarter than I can help you. ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Shepmaster! I meant aligned in general, but yes, my specific use case is for the stack. I'll update my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

huon's answer is good, but it's out of date.

As of Rust 1.25.0, [you may now align a type to `N` bytes using the attribute `#[repr(align(N))]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47006). It is documented under [the reference's Type Layout section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-align-representation). Note that the alignment must be a power of 2, you may not mix `align` and `packed` representations, and aligning a type may add extra padding to the type. [Here's an example of how to use the feature](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8f3adbedb562a6ad68e7ad68adcd6ea&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
#[repr(align(64))]
struct S(u8);

fn main() {
    println!("size of S: {}", std::mem::size_of::<S>());
    println!("align of S: {}", std::mem::align_of::<S>());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no way to specify alignment directly at the moment, but it is definitely desirable and useful. It is covered by [issue #33626](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33626), and its [RFC issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/325).

A current work-around to force alignment of some struct `Foo` to be as large as the alignment of some type `T` is to include a field of type `[T; 0]` which has size zero and so won't otherwise affect the behaviour of the struct, e.g. `struct Foo { data: A, more_data: B, _align: [T; 0] }`.

On nightly, this can be combined with SIMD types to get a specific high alignment, since they have alignment equal to their size (well, the next power of two), e.g.

```
#[repr(simd)]
struct SixteenBytes(u64, u64);

struct Foo {
    data: A,
    more_data: B,
    _align: [SixteenBytes; 0]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't Foo's alignment continue to be `std::mem::align_of<A>()`, but with a potentially increased `std::mem::size_of::<Foo>` reflecting padding inserted **after** B, to align `_align`?  How is `Foo`'s alignment affected at all by appending `_align: [T; 0]` to the `struct`'struct members?  Did you mean prepend?

Comment: The field can only be aligned statically if the start of the struct has a known alignment, because it always has a fixed offset from the start. Thus, this trick actually works no matter where the field is in the struct order.

Comment: I didn't know that--thank you.  So instead of requiring `(&struct + offset ) % desired_alignment == 0`, the compiler ensures `&struct % desired_alignment == 0 && offset % desired_alignment == 0?  That seems awfully wasteful, but I'm sure there must be a reason--can you point me to any resources on this to learn more?

Comment: The second is the only sensible way to ensure the first that I can think of. Not having the second would mean using a variable offset, which would have to be stored somewhere, and would likely waste more space. Also note that "incredibly wasteful" is a few bytes in a few structs.