# Can Rust struct alignment be controlled on the stable compiler?

Tags: rust, ffi, memory-alignment

I want to write a Rust FFI for a C struct using the `aligned` attribute.

On nightly, one can use `#[feature(repr_simd)]` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428153/how-can-i-align-a-struct-to-a-specifed-byte-boundary). The same technique without `#[repr(simd)]` appears to be restricted to a maximum alignment of 8 bytes.

There are various issues and RFCs open for both alignment and SIMD, and the compiler points to [tracking issue #27731](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27731) which seems to be stalled.

[RFC #325](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/325) points pretty clearly to no, but it is somewhat old.

Is it possible to do this with the stable compiler, in pure (unsafe?) Rust as of version 1.22?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, the answer is yes, you may specify a type's alignment in stable Rust. This was [stabilized in 1.25.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47006). It is documented under [the reference's Type Layout section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-align-representation). Note that the alignment must be a power of 2, you may not mix `align` and `packed` representations, and aligning a type may add extra padding to the type. [Here's an example of how to use the feature](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8f3adbedb562a6ad68e7ad68adcd6ea&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
#[repr(align(64))]
struct S(u8);

fn main() {
    println!("size of S: {}", std::mem::size_of::<S>());
    println!("align of S: {}", std::mem::align_of::<S>());
}
```